# Differential Equations involving exponentials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It's been sometime since I've had to solve a differential equation involving an exponential.
The DE is a separable

$$\begin{align}
& 2\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}y(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} + e^{y(x)} = 0\\
\implies& \frac{\mathrm{d}y(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} = -\frac{1}{2}e^{y(x)}\\
\implies& \frac{1}{e^{y(x)}}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}y(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} = -\frac{1}{2}\\
\implies& \int e^{-y(x)}\ \mathrm{d}y(x) = -\frac{1}{2}\int \mathrm{d}x\\
\implies& - e^{y(x)}= -\frac{1}{2}x+C\\
\implies& y(x) = \ln\left(\frac{1}{2}x+C\right)\\
\end{align}$$

I think this is the answer, but for some reason Wolfram Alpha gives $y(x) = -\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}x + C\right)$. Where did the negative come from?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your second last line should be
$$-e^{-y}=\frac{-1}2x+c$$
since
$$\int e^{-y}dy=-e^{-y}$$

Comment: Derp. You're right. Thanks.

Comment: @physicsmajor Would you accept my answer?

Comment: Yes, of course. I got you.

Answer (score 4):

You have  made an error in evaluating $$\int e^{-y(x)}dy(x)$$

The negative sign does not go away.